# Rolling Sum by 3 Conditions in R based on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat, rolling-sum

I've got a df and i need to perform a rolling sum in another dataframe based on the values of the first df

1. All the transactions of each company, by date & account
2. This is the dataframe I want to build with the balance at the end of the day with each company's account

| Date | Company | Account | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | a | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | b | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | b | 5 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | a | 12 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | a | 4 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | b | 4 |

| Date | Company | Account | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | a | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | b | 15 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | a | 26 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | b | 14 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | x | i |
| 2021-01-01 | B | y | i |
| 2021-01-02 | B | x | ii |
| 2021-01-02 | B | y | ii |

In Excel this would be something like a SUMIF where you state that the criteria must me Company & Account % Date<=Date

Thnks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, .(Value = sum(Value)), by = .(Date, Company, Account)][, .(Date, Value = cumsum(Value)), by = .(Company, Account)]
```

**results**

```
#    Company Account       Date Value
# 1:       A       a 2021-01-01    10
# 2:       A       a 2021-01-02    26
# 3:       A       b 2021-01-01    15
# 4:       A       b 2021-01-02    19
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628L, 18628L, 18628L, 18629L, 
18629L, 18629L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), Company = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Account = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", 
"b"), Value = c(10L, 10L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

**EDIT update on OP's extra requirement in the comments**

```
# same code as above
df <- df[, .(Value = sum(Value)), by = .(Date, Company, Account)][, .(Date, Value = cumsum(Value)), by = .(Company, Account)]

# now create a small table with the full range of dates per group
fullrange <- df[, .(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), "days")), .(Company, Account)]

# merge the two tables, missing dates will here get NA as value
output <- merge(df, fullrange, by = c("Company", "Account", "Date"), all = T)

# now replace the NA values with the previous value
setnafill(output, type = "locf", cols = "Value")

output

#    Company Account       Date Value
# 1:       A       a 2021-01-01    10
# 2:       A       a 2021-01-02    10
# 3:       A       a 2021-01-03    26
# 4:       A       b 2021-01-01    15
# 5:       A       b 2021-01-02    15
# 6:       A       b 2021-01-03    19

# changed the data a bit and replaced the 2021-01-02 for 2021-01-03
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18628L, 18628L, 18628L, 18630L, 
18630L, 18630L), class = "Date"), Company = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A"), Account = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b"), Value = c(10L, 
10L, 5L, 12L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Merijn! Thank u very much! I've never heard before about the dot as an operator in R. Your code successfully solved my issue, but another one arrived haha, the only problem I have is that this code states the daily balance in a specific row but always a transaction has been made. Now I should search for a way that I can print the balance to the days between movements for example if 2022-01-01 is 10 and 2022-01-03 is 15, I would need that 2022-01-02 shows 10, that is, the previous balance. Thanks again for your help I should build up from this point

Comment: I updated my answer to provide that. The dot can be used in data.table as a replacement here for list.

Comment: Merijn, thanks again for your collaboration, what Ive done is, an rbind() between the original data frame with all the transactions and one that I made using expand.grid() with all the combinations of dates accounts and companies for the range of date today - min(date). Finally used your code, and works great. Thnanks again for ypur support, I will study that dot operator further. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could write your code so anyone can reproduce it easier.
For example

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("2021-01-02", "2021-01-02"),
  Company = c("A", "A"),
  Account = c("a", "b"),
  Value = c(10, 12),
)
```

Anyway, have you tried something like:

```
aggregate(Value~Company+Account, data=df, FUN=sum)
```